# Consult the same table with filter value

Tags: sql, join, select, datatables

I would appreciate how can i get this result.
My original table:

```
   Date     | Indicator |   Value
2020-01-01  |     1     |  3000.00
2020-01-02  |     1     |  2500.00
2020-01-03  |     1     |  1000.00
2020-01-01  |     2     |  12.50
2020-01-02  |     2     |  13.23
2020-01-03  |     2     |  14.24
2020-01-01  |     3     |  150.00
2020-01-02  |     3     |  300.00
2020-01-03  |     3     |  200.00
```

I need to expanse the value of indicator 1 for the rest indicators
respecting the date.

```
   Date     | Indicator |   Value   |  Result
2020-01-01  |     1     |  3000.00  |  3000.00
2020-01-02  |     1     |  2500.00  |  2500.00
2020-01-03  |     1     |  1000.00  |  1000.00
2020-01-01  |     2     |  12.50    |  3000.00
2020-01-02  |     2     |  13.23    |  2500.00
2020-01-03  |     2     |  14.24    |  1000.00
2020-01-01  |     3     |  150.00   |  3000.00
2020-01-02  |     3     |  300.00   |  2500.00
2020-01-03  |     3     |  200.00   |  1000.00
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses a window function:

```
select t.*,
       first_value(value) over (partition by date order by indicator) as result
from t;
```